# Is there a standard way to plane a board at an angle?

Tags: thickness-planer

In some cases I would like to put a "draft" on a board, which means to have its surfaces not be parallel, but be at some specific small angle. For example, the illustration below shows what a board with a 3-degree draft looks like:

[image]

Is there a standard way to put a board in a sled or fixture of some type, so it can be planed at a slope like this?

Comment: Is the angle supposed to be from one end to the other of the board or across its width?  The illustration doesn't have any grain shown...

Answer (score 3):

*[I see that you have tagged this with the thickness-planer tag, so this answer probably does not apply because it refers to hand-planing. I'm leaving it here for posterity I guess.]*

The one technique I'm aware of (and have actually used!) that does not require special tools or jigs is to hand plane the board along its length in quarters.

That is to say, you apply some amount of strokes about a quarter of the way up the board, all the way across the width. Then do the same, but plane 1/2 the length. Then 3/4 of the length, then finally the whole board.

This results in a wedge profile that you can tune appropriately. I suppose one could tune the "quarters" to some other value to get a different profile.

Answer (score 3):

Joint one face first.  Then figure out how much thinner the small side should be and tape a shim that thick to the jointed face.  Run the board through the planer with the jointed/shimmed face down.

If the stock is thin enough that it might flex under the feed rollers add more (progressively smaller) shims along the length.  If the stock is still too thin to be safe then you could make an angled sled the same way and run the stock through on the sled.

Comment: I second this approach, it's exactly how I approached it when I had same need.